# Flutter, TextFormField: KeyBoard immediately disappears when it's opened

Tags: flutter, dart, textformfield, texteditingcontroller

I'm working on a login screen and I use TextFormField to insert a user's email and password. When I use a tablet emulator the keyboard immediately disappears after I click on it. It isn't for every emulator. With my real phone it works and also with another emulator. But with other three emulators it doesn't work. This are the imports:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:prcarpolimi/Internet/NetworkCheck.dart';
import 'package:prcarpolimi/auth/signUp.dart';
import 'package:prcarpolimi/auth/forgot_password.dart';
import 'package:prcarpolimi/models/marker_to_pass.dart';
import 'package:prcarpolimi/models/userModel.dart';
import 'package:prcarpolimi/homepage.dart';
import 'package:prcarpolimi/services/services.dart';
import '../models/static_user.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

And this is my code:

```
  final Service loginService;

  const Login({Key? key, required this.loginService}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  UserModel userModel = UserModel();
  static final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  static final _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  static final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool from = true;

  Future<User?> loginUsingEmailPassword(
      {required String email,
      required String password,
      required BuildContext context}) async {
    User? user;

    try {
      user = await widget.loginService.signInWithemailandpass(email, password);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == "user-not-found") {}
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: 'Login failed :( wrong email or password', fontSize: 20);
      return null;
    }

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (context) => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    );
    return user;
  }

  _finishReservation(User user) async {
    var data = await widget.loginService
        .firebasefirestore()
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .collection('booking-out')
        .get();

    if (data.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      for (var bookOut in data.docs) {
        String data = bookOut.data()['date'];
        final splitted = data.split('-');
        String finalDate = splitted[1];
        DateTime dayEnd = DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(finalDate);
        if (dayEnd.compareTo(DateTime.now()) < 0) {
          await widget.loginService
              .firebasefirestore()
              .collection('users')
              .doc(user.uid)
              .collection('booking-out')
              .doc(bookOut.data()['bookingId'])
              .update({'status': 'f'});
        }
      }
    }

    var data2 = await widget.loginService
        .firebasefirestore()
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .collection('cars')
        .get();

    if (data2.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      for (var car in data.docs) {
        await widget.loginService
            .firebasefirestore()
            .collection('users')
            .doc(car.data()['uid'])
            .collection('cars')
            .doc(car.data()['cid'])
            .collection('booking-in')
            .get()
            .then((ds) async {
          if (ds.docs.isNotEmpty) {
            for (var book in ds.docs) {
              String data = book.data()['date'];
              final splitted = data.split('-');
              String finalDate = splitted[1];
              DateTime dayEnd = DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(finalDate);
              if (dayEnd.compareTo(DateTime.now()) < 0) {
                await widget.loginService
                    .firebasefirestore()
                    .collection('users')
                    .doc(user.uid)
                    .collection('cars')
                    .doc(book.data()['cid'])
                    .collection('booking-in')
                    .doc(book.data()['bookingId'])
                    .update({'status': 'f'});
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final screenText = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor;

    final emailField = TextFormField(
        key: const ValueKey(1),
        autofocus: false,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: sizeHintText()),
        controller: _emailController,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        onSaved: (value) {
          _emailController.text = value!;
        },
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail, size: sizeHintText()),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(screenWidth * 0.02,
                screenHeight * 0.015, screenWidth * 0.02, screenHeight * 0.015),
            hintText: "Email",
            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: sizeHintText()),
            border:
                OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))));

    final passwordField = TextFormField(
        key: const ValueKey(2),
        autofocus: false,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: sizeHintText()),
        controller: _passwordController,
        obscureText: true,
        onSaved: (value) {
          _passwordController.text = value!;
        },
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.vpn_key, size: sizeHintText()),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(screenWidth * 0.02,
                screenHeight * 0.015, screenWidth * 0.02, screenHeight * 0.015),
            hintText: "Password",
            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: sizeHintText()),
            border:
                OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))));

       Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                  SizedBox(height: screenHeight * 0.1),
                  Text("Welcome to PrCar!",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: screenText * 45,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  SizedBox(height: screenHeight * 0.05),
                  SizedBox(
                      height: screenHeight * 0.2,
                      child: Image.asset("assets/prcarlogo.png",
                          fit: BoxFit.contain)),
                  SizedBox(height: screenHeight * 0.05),
                  emailField,
                  SizedBox(height: screenHeight * 0.02),
                  passwordField,
                  SizedBox(height: screenHeight * 0.05),
                  Row(children: [
                    SizedBox(width: screenWidth * 0.06),
                    GestureDetector(
                        child: Text('Forgot password?',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                color: Colors.redAccent,
                                fontSize: screenText * 16)),
                        onTap: () =>
                            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => const ForgotPasswordPage(),
                            ))),
                    Text(' or ', style: TextStyle(fontSize: screenText * 12)),
                    GestureDetector(
                        key: Key("New Account"),
                        child: Text("Don't have an account?",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                color: Colors.redAccent,
                                fontSize: screenText * 16)),
                        onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => const SignUp())))
                  ]),
                  SizedBox(height: screenHeight * 0.06),
                  Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
                    Container(
                        key: const Key("clickButtom"),
                        height: screenHeight * 0.07,
                        width: screenWidth * 0.85,
                        child: MaterialButton(
                            color: Colors.redAccent,
                            onPressed: () async {
                              if (await NetworkCheck().check()) {
                                User? user = await loginUsingEmailPassword(
                                    email: _emailController.text,
                                    password: _passwordController.text,
                                    context: context);
                                if (user != null) {
                                  await widget.loginService
                                      .firebasefirestore()
                                      .collection('users')
                                      .doc(user.uid)
                                      .get()
                                      .then((ds) {
                                    userModel = UserModel.fromMap(ds);
                                    StaticUser.email = userModel.email!;
                                    StaticUser.uid = userModel.uid!;
                                    StaticUser.firstName = userModel.firstName!;
                                    StaticUser.secondName =
                                        userModel.secondName!;
                                    PassMarker.from = true;
                                    _finishReservation(user);
                                    Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) => HomePage(
                                                homePageService: Service())));
                                  });
                                }
                              } else {
                                Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                    msg: 'No internet connection',
                                    fontSize: 20);
                              }
                            },
                            child: Text("Login",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: screenText * 25))),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.deepPurple,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                            boxShadow: const [
                              BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.deepPurple,
                                  spreadRadius: 6,
                                  blurRadius: 3)
                            ]))
                  ])
                ])));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to add this line

```
onSaved: (value) {
          _passwordController.text = value!;
        },
```

controller will automatically update text when you change in textformfield

Comment: I delete this line but it doesn't still work